# private memory for specific processes

Tags: linux, process, memory, memory-management

(assuming `root` account is not involved in this matter;)

is it possible for two processes to share a piece of memory that only they can access? the best i can think of is to create a dedicated user for those 2 processes; i would like to know if we can do the same thing without creating additional user accounts on the system;

(if os type matters, it is linux not unix;)

Comment: create a file that owns by the dedicated user , permit 0700, then mmap over this file in both process , it is shared file actually , but  ops  memory via mmap .

Comment: man 2 mmap to read the manpage , it is standard syscall in most *nix systems.

Comment: System 5 IPC has shared memory which also obeys user restrictions, man sysvipc

Comment: @bigdataolddriver in fact i am asking whether we can do this without the dedicated user;

Comment: as far as I know, process and file access are both limited to user id level, not pid. If you run two processes sharing a file , another process with same user id can still do chmod/rm/mv etc over that file.

Comment: Are the processes related (i.e parent or grandparent and child) or are they arbitrary? Do you need it to be certain that the memory can not be shared or just it will not be shared accidentally? How do the 2 processes currently communicate (if at all)?

Comment: @icarus it is not guaranteed one will be the parent of another; the requirement is only those 2 processes can access the memory, all the time; i guess using other kinds of ipc is fine, but shared memory is more favorable;

Comment: The question I am trying to figure out is the privacy part. If processes A & B can access the shared memory how do we stop C? Typically this means A & B have to have a shared secret or a way to communicate. So I repeat the ask, how certain does it need to be be that C can not get access to the shared memory, and how do A and B communicate or do they have a shared secret (so C can not pretend to be B)?

Comment: @icarus you can assume kernel knows about what are A and B and denies access request from C; and the question is we want kernel to allocate a private communication channel between A and B;

Comment: Things don't work like that. The point of the question is how to deny the access from C. From a very high level point of view, the kernel treats all processes the same. Looking a little more closely it distinguishes them based on if it is running as root or not, looking more closely still it differentiates based on user and group and capabilities and limits. So to answer your question we need to know how we can tell the difference between A, B, and C. You appear to want to rule out using user as a way to tell them apart, so we need to peer even more closely at A, B &C to tell them apart.